# aac bitstream error when writing mp4 file

Tags: ffmpeg

My application receives an audio-video stream from an RTSP source and writes it out to an mp4 file using libffmpeg.

I set up the audio output stream to use aac encoding and configured it this way:

```
            stream->codec->sample_fmt = codec->sample_fmts ? codec->sample_fmts[0] : AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;
            stream->codec->bit_rate = 64000;
            stream->codec->sample_rate = pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->codec->sample_rate;
            stream->codec->channels = 1;
            stream->codec->channel_layout = av_get_default_channel_layout(1);
            stream->codec->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
```

This seems like it should work. However when I run the application I get the error message "aac bitstream error", and the resulting mp4 file plays back without any audio.

I'm at a dead end right now. I don't know how to find out more about what this error means. Does anyone know?

Comment: Is your bitstream ASC? See https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/aac_adtstoasc_bsf.c

Comment: Can you post a link to short sample mp4 with this issue?

Comment: I'm not really sure what an ASC bitstream is. The source audio is PCM (unencoded). The actual codec reported by ffmpeg is AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16BE. That's not a codec that MP4 files support, which is why I'm trying to transcode it into AAC.